# Is there a way to use monad comprehensions with Kotlin Flow

Tags: kotlin, monads, kotlin-coroutines, arrow-kt

Kotlin coroutines and Arrow are a nice way to avoid nesting flatmaps, introducing monadic comprehensions in Kotlin. However Kotlin's `Flow` type still relies on declarative flatmapping, so we get into a mixture of direct and declarative styles:

```
    override suspend fun findAll(page: Pageable): Either<BusinessException, Flow<PageElement<ClientOut>>> = either {
        val count = clientRepository.count().awaitSingle().bind()
        return clientRepository.findByIdNotNull(page).asFlow()
            .flatMapMerge { client ->
                flow { emit(mapDetailedClientOut(client)) }
            }
    }
```

`val count` has been bound inside the `either {...}` comprehension. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to do the same with `Flow`, forcing us to nest a `flatmapMerge()`.

Is there a way to do it, or is it planned to be somehow included in the near future?

Comment: I don't believe we refer to the same thing when talking about *callback hell*. IMO callbacks are a specific usage of function arguments, mostly to call some originator back once an asynchronous process is done, or repeatedly as a concurrent process occurs. I'm not sure it's fair to associate any higher-order function to callback hell

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it correctly. What I'm looking for is a way to replace flatmap calls with a nonblocking sequential execution. https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/monad_comprehensions/ shows how to do it for types such as Either, the problem is Flow doesn't fit into this, so we have to mix the sequentil style (`.bind()`) and a declarative style (`Flow.flatmapMerge`). Libraries suchs as Scala's ZIO allow it for an equivalent type (ZStream) https://zio.dev/next/datatypes/stream/zstream/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly there is currently no way to build comphrehensions for the KotlinX `Flow` datatype, since Coroutines in Kotlin only support for single-shot emission/`bind`.

Therefore it's only possible to build comphrensions for data types with `0..1` elements such as `Either` or `Nullable`, but not `0..N` like the `Flow` or `List` data types.